Warning upgrading from Almalinux 8 to 9: OpenSSH configuration file will get updated to RHEL9 version, no longer allowing root login with password
Trying to upgrade Almalinux 8 to 9 using sudo leapp upgrade as the root user on a fresh vps. How can I quickly solve this problem so that I can upgrade the server os without the root user getting locked out?

Risk Factor: high (inhibitor)
Title: Possible problems with remote login using root account
Summary: OpenSSH configuration file will get updated to RHEL9 version, no longer allowing root login with password. It is a good practice to use non-root administrative user and non-password authentications, but if you rely on the remote root login, this change can lock you out of this system.
Remediation: [hint] If you depend on remote root logins using passwords, consider setting up a different user for remote administration or adding a comment into the sshd_config next to the "PermitRootLogin yes" directive to prevent rpm replacing it during the upgrade.
Key: 3d21e8cc9e1c09dc60429de7716165787e99515f
For the Remediation, you can add a comment next to PermitRootLogin yes in order to bypass this.

